# Add searchBar in navigationBar after viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

In my application, I want to have a search button in the navigation bar and when the button is pressed  searchbar should appear in the Navigation Bar. I've seen many posts on the subject, but somehow it does not work for me.
So, I placed a `SearchDisplayController` right below nav bar. then in the `viewDidLoad` I assign an action to the search button and remove searchbar from superview. Once button is clicked, I am calling `mapSearchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true`, but nothing happends. Code extracts below:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            banner.delegate = self

            // Add button to navbar
            var filterButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Organize, target: self, action: nil)
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = filterButton

            var aboutButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: "aboutAction")
            var searchButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search, target: self, action: "searchAction")
            var rButtons : [UIBarButtonItem] = [aboutButton, searchButton]
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = rButtons


            // Deal with Search Display Controller
            self.mapSearchDisplayController.delegate = self.mapSearchDisplayController;
            self.mapSearchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self.mapSearchDisplayController;
            self.mapSearchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self.mapSearchDisplayController;
            self.mapSearchDisplayController.searchBar.removeFromSuperview();
}
    func searchAction(){
            println("Search action")
            mapSearchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true
        }
```

If I call `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true` in `viewDidLoad` then `searchBar` correctly appears in the Navigation Bar. 
How do I make appear in Nav bar on the button press?
Any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

I created a search bar using

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame : CGRect(0, 0, self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width)! * 0.9, 0)

self.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
self.searchBar.delegate = self
```

And then added it to the navigation bar as follows:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar
```

Further styling etc can also be done but I just created and added it to the navbar on button pressed and removed it from superview when it needed to be hidden.